# Php, flip array values into array keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Article
            [item_en] => home
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Section
            [item_en] => contact
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => Block
            [item_en] => login
        )

)
```

And I would like to make it into this:

```
Array
(
    [Article] => Array
        (
            [item_en] => home
        )

    [Section] => Array
        (
            [item_en] => contact
        )

    [Block] => Array
        (
            [item_en] => login
        )

)
```

So that each type key becomes parent key.

I have tried using array_flip() but that does not work in this case. Is there any built in php function that can do that?

Comment: PHP version >= 7 ? `array_column()` : `array_map()` + `array_combine()`